# gcc / clang: -fmax-errors / -ferror-limit: why the triggering condition is "exceeded" rather than "reached"?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, clang, limit, diagnostics

Sample code (t999.c):

```
int_ x;
```

Incvocatoins:

```
$ gcc t999.c -fmax-errors=1
t999.c:1:1: error: unknown type name ‘int_’; did you mean ‘int’?
    1 | int_ x;
      | ^~~~
      | int


$ clang t999.c -ferror-limit=1
t999.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'int_'; did you mean 'int'?
int_ x;
^~~~
int
1 error generated.
```

Here we see that:

1. gcc have not generated `compilation terminated due to -fmax-errors=1`.
2. clang have not generated `fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]`.

Conclusion: in both gcc and clang the triggering condition is "exceeded" rather than "reached".

Descriptions:

> -fmax-errors=n
>
> Limits the maximum number of error messages to n, at which point GCC
> bails out rather than attempting to continue processing the source
> code.

> -ferror-limit=123
>
> Stop emitting diagnostics after 123 errors have been produced.

Questions:

1. Why the triggering condition is "exceeded" rather than "reached"?
2. Should the triggering condition be "reached" rather than "exceeded"?
3. (extra) Does the current behavior ("exceeded" rather than "reached") correspond to the descriptions above?

Comment: I think the only answerable question here is #3.  #1 is just an arbitrary design decision and #2 is opinion-based.  And even #3 is not really about program behavior but at most the clarity of the documentation.